# October CMS | display images on reordering lists

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

There are a way to turn ON the reorder functionality on the list controller and re-order list items by `name` for example...

But there are some way to display images instead of a text on a reorder list?

[image]

What I have for now:

*config_reorder.yaml*

```
title: 'Configurar a ordem'
azuRef: ref
azuImg: image
modelClass: Frama\Azulejos\Models\Azulejo
toolbar:
buttons: reorder_toolbar
```

*ReorderController.php*

```
...
public function __construct($controller)
{
    ...

    $this->azuImg = $this->getConfig('azuImg', $this->azuImg);

    ...

}
...
```

And as result of course I get text... And I don't know what to do with that... I need to access to path or (better) `getThumb`

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Ok I can get a path with something like that, by transforming a sting:

```
json_decode($this->reorderGetRecordImg($record))->path
```

But how to make a thumb work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **SOLUTION**

Well the solution was easy as ***k :)

*modules/backend/behaviors/rendercontroller/partials/_records.htm*

```
<?php foreach ($records as $record): ?>
    <!-- ... -->

    <img src="<?= $record->image->getThumb(50,'auto',['mode' => 'landscape']) ?>" alt="">

     <!-- ... -->
<?php endforeach ?>
```

**OR:**

*modules/backend/behaviors/rendercontroller/partials/_records.htm*

```
<?php foreach ($records as $record): ?>
    <!-- ... -->

    <img src="<?= $this->reorderGetRecordImg($record) ?>" alt="">

     <!-- ... -->
<?php endforeach ?>
```

*ReorderController.php*

```
...
public function __construct($controller)
{
    ...

    $this->azuImg = $this->getConfig('azuImg', $this->azuImg);

    ...

}
...
public function reorderGetRecordImg($record)
{
    return $record->image->getThumb(50,'auto',['mode' => 'landscape']);
}
...
```

Comment: Please note that it is generally a bad idea to override system core files, as your changes will be deleted on the next platform update. However, in this case I am unsure if this can be solved in a better way. So its just a heads u!